# AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle vs. SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony

[AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle](http://knpbundles.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle) vs. [SonataAdminBundle](http://knpbundles.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle)

I am starting a new Symfonfy2.2 Project and I need a Admin Backend. I used the old AdminGenerator in Symonfy1.4, and was quite happy with it. Everything worked more or less out of the box. If you check KNPBundles for Admin Backends, then you will most likely find two Admin Backends, that have enough score, to be relevant in a buisiness critical application.

The Question is,
which one would you prefer and why? Especially when it comes to things like:

- customizability
- effort to install and maintain
- number of bugs or errors
- long term development

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can say is that IMHO the AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle generate cached code that is specific to the entity you're CRUD'ing, while SonataAdminBundle does all at runtime.

Sonata has already been reused in other extra libraries like smyfony-CMF.